# Change array dimensions of function parameter in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, numpy, parameter-passing

I am using python3 and numpy. I have following code on many places in my

```
if contour.condition:
     contour = contour[0, :, :]
```

I want to do it in a function like

```
 def CorrectContour(contour):
     if contour.condition:
         contour = contour[0, :, :]
```

But this change only the the copy of contour. How can I do this? I accept other suggestions, except functions.

Answer (score 1):

`contour[0,:,:]` makes a new array, a `view`.  `contour=...` assigns the new array to the variable.  What's different in the function is that `contour` is now a local variable, breaking the connection with the input argument.

This should behave the same as your original code:

```
def CorrectContour(contour):
     if contour.condition:
         contour = contour[0, :, :]
     return contour
contour = CorrectContour(contour)
```

Comment: Well this is good suggestion, but what I wanted was to use just one parameter in function to avoid the double usage of same variable "contour"